# Create Google Document with Python

Tags: python, google-authentication

I'm trying to use Google API to create new google document (for automation of requests review)

I'm using the following code from "Example" from Google, and it doesn't work for me:
https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples/blob/master/docs/quickstart/quickstart.py

When I executing this script I'm getting error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_docs.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "google_docs.py", line 31, in main
    'credentials.json', SCOPES)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 199, in from_client_secrets_file
    return cls.from_client_config(client_config, scopes=scopes, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 159, in from_client_config
    'Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.')
ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.
```

Note: I've create a Service account, and the following code works just fine with the same credentials:

```
import gspread


client = gspread.service_account(filename='credentials.json')

sheet = client.open('Test').sheet1
print(sheet.get_all_records())
```

So, I guess it means that credentials file is correct, but I wonder what can I change to be able to create Google Documents, not only spreadsheets...

Answer (score 4):

After several hours of experiments and frustration I've found one dirty workaround:

```
import gspread
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


# The ID of a sample document.
DOCUMENT_ID = '195j9eDD3ccgjQRttHhJPymLJUCOUjs-jmwTrekvdjFE'

client = gspread.service_account(filename='credentials.json')

service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=client.auth)
document = service.documents().get(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID).execute()
print('The title of the document is: {}'.format(document.get('title')))
```

so, I will put it here just in case if somebody will face the same issue I had today :)